# laravel upgraded 5.4 to 5.5 and having issue of 401 unauthorized ajax

Tags: laravel-5.5, laravel-passport, unauthorized

I have upgraded my application Laravel version 5.4 to 5.5.

Having issue for passport , I have updated that also with 4.0

But still getting 401 (Unauthorized)